# How to have C output ≤ and ≥ symbols in the output instead of?

Tags: c

I'd like for my C program to output ≥ and ≤ symbols from printf() instead of replacing them with ?. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: That depends a lot on your environment.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on your OS and terminal emulator.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm assuming Windows, because most other OSes get this right by default.

Comment: It's not necessarily about the compiler - it's about the shell where you run your program: does it support those characters?  To check, run your program and redirect the output to a file and then open the file in an editor.

Comment: Do you still get a `?` (or any output other than a single ≥ on a line by itself) from `puts("\xE2\x89\xA5")`?

Comment: It would also be useful to know what you get from `puts("\xFE");` and `puts("\x86");`

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: yes, it is possible to output symbols like ≤ and ≥ using `printf()`.

I just compiled and ran this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("≤ ≥ \n");
    printf("\342\211\244 \342\211\245 \n");
}
```

When I run it, it prints two lines of

```
≤ ≥
```

which is just what I expect.

Now, it's important to add that I compiled and ran this on my Mac.  There's a Terminal preferences dialog I can open, and one of the "advanced" settings I've got is "Character encoding", which I normally have set to "Unicode (UTF-8)".  That's a good choice.  But if I temporarily change it to "Western (ISO Latin 1)", the program prints

```
â¤ â¥
```

instead, which is not surprising if you know how these encodings work, but is obviously not what was intended.

If I were to run this program on one of my Linux machines, I would expect it to work just the same.  On those machines, if I wanted to switch to an encoding other than the default UTF-8, there's some similar terminal properties dialog I might use, but I don't remember where it is or how it works, and I expect it might differ considerably between different versions of Linux.

And I gather there are similar settings to worry about on a Windows machine, but I don't use Windows as much, so I'm not sure of the details, and I'm not sure how likely it is that UTF-8 is the default.

I should point out that the code I've posted here is just an experiment, to see whether your terminal window or other output system can (or can be made to) support UTF-8 output.  This is not necessarily the best or the most portable way to do extended-character output.

Specifically, my first line,

```
    printf("≤ ≥ \n");
```

is poor form because it's not necessarily guaranteed you can use Unicode characters directly in ordinary string literals, and my second line,

```
    printf("\342\211\244 \342\211\245 \n");
```

is poor because it *assumes* UTF-8.  (Your output subsystem might, theoretically, use a wider-than-ASCII representation other than UTF-8.  But it's unlikely; UTF-8 is, or ought to be, nearly everywhere by now.)

Better (more portable) would be to also include `<wchar.h>` and to use `wprintf` and a wide-character string constant (as suggested in Nominal Animal's answer):

```
wprintf(L"Here are ≤ and ≥ \n");
```

It's probably best to explicitly set the locale when using these; see  Nominal Animal's answer for details.

There are also "universal" character constants, as suggested in Jonathan Leffler's comment:

```
printf("\u2264 \u2265 \n");
```

(This last should perhaps use the `L` modifier and `wprintf` also; I'm not sure.)

---

Addendum: yet another way to print Unicode characters is to convert them individually to multibyte (typically UTF-8) sequences using `wctomb()`:

```
char le[MB_LEN_MAX+1];
char ge[MB_LEN_MAX+1];
int r = wctomb(le, 0x2264);   /* U+2264: <= */
le[r] = '\0';
r = wctomb(ge, 0x2265);       /* U+2264: >= */
ge[r] = '\0';
printf("%s %s\n", le, ge);
```

Comment: I was able to add the line `printf("\u2264 \u2265\n");` and get a third line of identical output — also running on a Mac (using both `clang` and GCC 8.1.0).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, nice.  I'm not sure I knew about those.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your code to be portable, use wide character output. The following code is standard C (C99 or later):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, ""))
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Current locale is not supported by the C library.\n");
    if (fwide(stdin, 1) < 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Standard input does not support wide characters.\n");
    if (fwide(stdout, 1) < 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Standard output does not support wide characters.\n");

    wprintf(L"Here are ≤ and ≥.\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

On Linux systems (and on Macs, too, I believe), if you have a locale that can display ≤ and ≥, that is what you will get.  In other locales, you'll see `Here are <= and >=.` instead.

If you need to be able to use narrow standard input and output functions (for example, because you use other code using those), use

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, ""))
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Current locale is not supported by the C library.\n");

    printf("Here are %lc and %lc.\n", L'≤', L'≥');

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

instead. Unfortunately, this tends to have issues with locales that cannot support the ≤ and ≥ characters (on my system, the output is then just `Here are` without a newline). I personally would use the first approach instead.

Comment: Very nice answer.  (Not sure why someone downvoted it -- you've paid much more attention to proper portability than my answer did.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: I'm definitely an [UTF8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) type of person myself, and would prefer to only support UTF-8 locales; I normally write code very similar to your answer. But, for learning purposes, the wide-character portable way is better: first learn the rules, then why and how the break them, sort of approach. :)  The downvote came almost certainly from a Windows user, as Microsoft still refuses to support Unicode locales unless you add some proprietary Microsoft-only calls to your C code. (That is, this example would need additional code to work on Windows.)

Comment: Oh, my.  Somehow I had never known that.  Thanks for the tip.  (Deleted my suggestion.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: I haven't checked any of the implementations to find out whether it works in practice; it is so clearly forbidden by the [`man fwide`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fwide.3.html), as well as C99 7.19.2p4. Note, however, that one can use [`freopen(NULL, mode, stream)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3.html) to "reset" the stream orientation. (I'd do a `fflush(stream)` before that call, though.)

Comment: In any case, it certainly reinforces the notion of "UTF-8 everywhere", doesn't it?  (By which I mean, if you're implicitly using UTF-8, or explicitly calling `wcstombs` and the like when you need to, you can keep using regular "narrow" streams, and never have to worry about the wide ones.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: Wide character I/O leads naturally to wide curses, though. You cannot really use UTF-8 sequences with narrow curses; too many glitches. To do any kind of text UI, curses is the best choice; and if it utilizes peoples' names or Unicode glyphs (for games!), wide curses is the best option. So, I think I'll keep pushing the wide character stuff for C newbies. :)